# Meta Refresh To Relative File

Tags: php, html, web-applications, refresh, meta-tags

I'm making a web app and I'm checking for the presence of a configuration file to determine whether or not to run the installation script. However, since it is a web app, I have no idea at what URL this script will be stored.

Is there any way to redirect a page, either using PHP or HTML, to a relative file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reconstruct the URL of the currently executing script using the 'SCRIPT_NAME' variable set by mod_php. From there it's just a matter of relative path manipulation to construct the absolute URL of the script you want to redirect to.

```
<?php
$scheme = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http';
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$basedir = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
header("Location: {$scheme}://{$host}{$basedir}/redirect_target_page.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I could just do this:

`header('Location: ./install.php')`

Comment: Many (most?) modern browsers correctly handle relative URIs in the Location header, but it is against the HTTP/1.1 spec (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you can use `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');` but it must be used with full url, not the relative one, so you just need to build full url from your relative url and use `header`

Comment: Untrue. Actually, I just found the solution, read in my answer.

Comment: also you can do it on client side using javascript, but if you can figure out that redirect is needed on server side , better to do it on server side